# Finding New Max/Min Points In a List

Tags: python, list

I am currently working with historical stock data in python with pandas datareader analyzing data from the last 250 trading days. One objective I am trying to accomplish is finding each time a new max price or min price occurs in the data. 
An example of what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
max_point = []
min_point = []
test = []
for x in aapl[1][:]:
    test.append(x)
    if x > max(test):
        max_point.append(x)
    if x < min(test):
        min_point.append(x)
```

This is my current non-working code, and I was wondering if I could get some insight on how to correctly write this code. Since I am relatively new to python, any other tips on the best ways to work with list iterations would also greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give me an example of what is `aapl`?

Comment: And what is the desired output?

Comment: And do you get an error? if so please post the whole trace back

Comment: aapl is just my variable name I have set for all stock data relating to Apple in the Pandas Datareader. aapl[1] is then referring to specifically the closing data. My desired output is a list of max points and min points that is acquired each time a new max or new min occurs when iterating through the list

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide us detailed information about your problem.
But as far as I have understood your problem I think this code should work.

code:-

```
max_point = []
min_point = []
test = [] 

for x in aapl[1][:]: 
    test.append(x) 


max_point.append(max(test)) 
min_point.append(min(test))
```

Hope it helps. If not then don't hesitate to ask me.
Cheers.

Comment: I am getting a value error saying 'the truth value of this series is ambiguous" but this could easily be an error with my code

Comment: Can you tell me what aapl[1] is?